# javascript use the same name for event function but still show function not find

Tags: javascript, html, function, events

I write simple javascript&HTML events:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" onclick="removetopic(this)">del</button>
```

and javascript:

```
function removetopic(ele) {
alert("ddd");
return 0;
}
```

you can see the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2pFYz/1/)

but in my firefox 29.0.1(firebug) run it. It always give me error from console:

```
ReferenceError: removetopic is not defined
```

I think I define the same name with trigger event onclick why the function is not defined?

Comment: select no wrap in fiddle. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pFYz/2/)

Comment: +1 to @GovindSinghNagarkoti. When defined in onLoad, the function is local to the onLoad closure. It has to be global to be used in HTML attributes.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine..Have you include jquery in your code..
check this http://plnkr.co/edit/SiRd0IhUISPVvwXaejpl?p=preview
Its your same code and it works just fine.